# Is there any implementation of weak reference with timeout?

Tags: .net, weak-references

Sometimes I need to hold a reference to object in memory during some time. Weak reference allows this but the time is limited by the garbage-collection cycle. The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971530/weak-reference-with-a-condition-timeout) but is related to .NET.

I know that there are many caches that have such feature built in but I don't need to utilize a full cache (which is a Key-Value map) to store only one object. It would rather be a single "expirable reference".

I know that I can implement this myself but I'm looking for a standard implementation (ideally integrated in the framework, in case I've missed it)

**UPDATE**

Based on the answers from @Jeroen Mostert and @dariogriffo I add more details to the question.

Ok, so there are two ways: either use key-value cache or timer-based callback. Lets assume there is a tree of objects each having a reference to a cached value. These values have an expiration timeout. Assume count of tree nodes is large. If I store each value in the MemoryCahce this requires to assign unique keys to the nodes and access to their values is made by hash table search. Also it has some computation complexity of adding new keys to the table. From the other hand if I use my custom `WeakReferenceByTimeOut` as @dariogriffo suggests then It doesn't have such problems. Instead, there is an overhead because I need to create one timer object per value object (or Task object that is using timer internally, I guess). From my point of view the second approach is better but I'm not sure.

Comment: Write it by your own...

Comment: Just use a normal reference and set it to `null` when the time is over?

Comment: So you need a strong reference to go weak after particular time? Or..? It will be trivial to implement with a timer.

Comment: Of course I can but the question is: Are there are any standard implementations of that. (I'll correct the description)

Comment: @neleus Your requirement isn't standard. It is very very specific one, so there's no implementation in .Net framework. If you ask for any other implementations, that is off topic as you're asking for off-site resource.

Comment: I know you said you don't need a full cache, but there's no harm in making use the one built into .NET, even if it's just for a single item: [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) It allows you to very easily expire items.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in as far as I know either, so here goes a 1 minute implementation

```
using System.Timers;

public class WeakReferenceByTimeOut<T> where T : class
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public WeakReferenceByTimeOut(T val, int miliseconds)
    {
        Reference = val;
        _timer = new Timer(miliseconds);
        _timer.Elapsed += KillReference;
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public T Reference { get; private set; }

    private void KillReference(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Elapsed -= KillReference;
        _timer.Dispose();
        _timer = null;

        Reference = null;   
    }        
}
```

Comment: `using(_timer){}` is a very strange way to write `_timer.Dispose()`, IMHO.

Comment: So what timer is it? [This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Henrik, yes it is, but I use as a reminder that I always have to dispose things. Is kind of a OCD

Comment: You should set `timer.AutoReset = false` otherwise `KillReference` could be fired multiple times.

Comment: @Henrik: actually, it's `if (_timer != null) _timer.Dispose();`. `using` doesn't care if you pass `null`, making this a convenient way of disposing a field whether it's been assigned or not.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes makes convenient(Irony) and confusing also.

Comment: @JeroenMostert In this case, the method is only called from the timer event itself, so unless there is a really weird race condition going on, this will most likely not be null. That said, a little defensive code doesn't hurt much.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: of course; I'm talking about the general case where this idiom is used in a `Dispose()` which may very well be called on half-constructed objects. Even then a `NullReferenceException` will just be swallowed by the finalizer, but it's nice if it's robust enough to dispose everything.

Comment: It is safer to use `Interlocked.Exchange(ref Reference, null)`

Comment: @neleus even better: `Interlocked.Exchange(ref _timer, null)?.Dispose()`

Answer (score 2):

If it's important to your requirements that an entry should not be valid for more than a certain amount of time, well, you *do* need a cache of some sort, even if it's just a cache of one. The simplest implementation (if you never set the reference to anything else) is `Task.Delay(...).ContinueWith(t => myWeakReference = null)`, which requires no additional class. If you do need the ability to set the reference to something else (which means resetting the timer) you'll need a wrapper class.

I don't recommed writing a class with support for setting the reference to something else, by the way -- there is an inherent race condition between setting the reference and clearing it just when the timer expires. If you need something like this, a vetted cache implementation with policies is almost certainly better, even if you do use it for just one reference.

There is nothing like this in the BCL; it's an unusual scenario. Usually you would either cache multiple values, or you don't care when exactly the reference gets cleaned up as long as the cache stays within certain memory limits. If you have a cache with a timeout policy, like [System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx), you can store `WeakReference` instances in that, which should achieve the same thing (but you need to double check that the entry you get back from the cache is still valid).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: yes -- the OP specifically stated that he didn't want to use a cache because it's "just one" reference, but it's certainly not wrong to use a cache anyway. I updated my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: Agree that my task is not trivial. I've added more details to the question. Now I wonder what is better in my case. It would be nice to see cons and pros of each approach.